# Predicates on views: How can I evaluate the predicate before the view joins?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM vwTimeBlocks 
WHERE vwTimeBlocks.id = @id 
   AND vwTimeBlocks.organization = @org
```

`organization` is indexed in some of the tables within the view. I *expected* that the `WHERE` would be evaluated on the underlying tables in the view *before* any `JOINs`, but this isn't the case:

The execution plan suggests that the `WHERE` is being applied on the result of `vwBlocks`. Replacing the `vwBlocks` definition gives me this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
( SELECT  ... all the things...
  FROM tblTimeBlocks 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblA 
  ON tblA.id = tblTimeBlocks.F
    AND tblTimeBlocks.B = 1000
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB 
  ON tblB.id = tblTimeBlocks.F
    AND tblTimeBlocks.B = 2000
) AS subTimeBlocks
  WHERE subTimeBlocks.id = @timeblock AND subTimeBlocks.organization = @org;
```

Comparing the execution plan of this against the original query shows they're identical. However, when I place the `WHERE` clause inside the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
( SELECT  ... all the things...
  FROM tblTimeBlocks 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblA 
  ON tblA.id = tblTimeBlocks.F
    AND tblTimeBlocks.B = 1000
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB 
  ON tblB.id = tblTimeBlocks.F
    AND tblTimeBlocks.B = 2000
  WHERE subTimeBlocks.id = @timeblock AND subTimeBlocks.organization = @org
) AS subTimeBlocks
```

The overall query cost drops, and the execution plan for the new query is much better; here's a comparison, with the top execution plan showing the `WHERE` outside the subquery, and the bottom plan with the `WHERE` inside the subquery.

Note that the relative costs of the queries is at 91%-9%, and the first filters on `organization` quite late, while the second uses two seeks. 
[image: Comparative execution plans]

**Why** is this the case? I expected the query optimizer to optimize better than it did.

**Given this situation**, I'd obviously like to use the second query, and somehow push the predicate into the `view` portion of the query. Because the predicate relies on a parameter, I can't just alter the view definition. One option is to replace the view with a table-defined function, but this situation is replicated all over my database. Is there any other way?

Is there any way I can hint, or otherwise ask sqlserver to use the predicate in my view? I don't know *why* the query optimizer doesn't look at the query and push the `WHERE` as early as possible.

---

In case it's relevant, this is running on:
`Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8`

Comment: Normally it does push it through. Since you're using parameters it might be parameter sniffing. I'm not sure if I've seen it for views but try anyway... can your run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` (assuming this is not a production server) then recheck the query plan

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Unfortunately, this is on a production server. :(

Comment: In that case try using “Option (recompile)” like this. http://thinknook.com/sql-server-recompile-query-option-2011-12-22/ also have a read about parameter sniffing.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yeah, I'll look into parameter sniffing. Thanks for the heads up on that. Using `option (recompile)` doesn't alter the execution plan, though.

Comment: If you heard code the value it add a dummy column does it change?